# How to make these image tiles responsive

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, frontend

I have 3 image tiles (***Image and Description***) within a **div** element. I have used a ***flexbox*** such that all the 3 tiles are shown side by side in a row in full screen view. But when shown in a smaller screen, I want 2 of the tiles to be in the first row and the third tile to start a new second row. I tried it by giving the tile ***width 33%*** in the full screen case and ***width 50%*** in the smaller screen view but it isn't working mostly because I've made some mistake.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.tile {
  width: 33%;
}
  .img {
    width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 685px) {

.tile{
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="tile">          
        <img class="img" src="Sld1.jpg">
        <p>Img1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">      
        <img class="img" src="Sld2.jpg" >
        <p>Img2</p> 
    </div>

    <div class="tile">
        <img class="img" src="Sld3.jpg">
        <p>Img3</p>         
    </div>

</div>
```

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="tile">          
        <img class="img" src="Sld1.jpg">
        <p>Img1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tile">      
        <img class="img" src="Sld2.jpg" >
        <p>Img2</p> 
    </div>
        
    <div class="tile">
        <img class="img" src="Sld3.jpg">
        <p>Img3</p>         
    </div>

</div>

<style>
  .container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.tile {
  width: 33%;
}
  .img {
    width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 685px) {

.tile{
  width:50%;
}
}
</style>
```

I cant quite figure out what to write in the media screen function such that in small screen view there are 2 tiles in upper row and the third div tile of container moves to another row below it. Please help me out with the CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to add `flex-wrap: wrap` inside your container class.

```
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `flex-wrap: wrap` so the flex container will wrap at break points and then you can set up a class to break the wrap in media query with `flex-basis`. Just add that class to the div with the ***tile*** selector.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tile {
  width: 33%;
}

.img {
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 685px) {
.tile {
  width: 50%;
}

.break {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 55%; /* Change to 100% if you want it to fill up entire area under two images on top */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <div class="tile two">          
        <img class="img" src="Sld1.jpg">
        <p>Img1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="tile two">      
        <img class="img" src="Sld2.jpg" >
        <p>Img2</p> 
    </div>
        
    <div class="tile break">
        <img class="img" src="Sld3.jpg">
        <p>Img3</p>         
    </div>

</div>
```